# ssh-add fails when using ed25519 keys

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I've been upgrading my ssh keys on all my machines, and came across a bit of weirdness with ssh-add.

If I create an ed25519 key and then try to ssh-add it fails. If I take the original rsa key, and convert it with ssh-keygen then ssh-add it works.

reproduce the problem

```
# ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -a 256
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/trevor/.ssh/id_ed25519): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/trevor/.ssh/id_ed25519.
Your public key has been saved in /home/trevor/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub.
```

Now lets try to add it.

```
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/trevor/.ssh/id_ed25519: 
Could not add identity "/home/trevor/.ssh/id_ed25519": communication with agent failed
```

If I try to add a normal rsa key it works

```
# ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/trevor/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/trevor/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/trevor/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Have I found a bug with ssh-add or is it a problem with Ubuntu.

Running all the above on Ubuntu 16.04LTS

```
apt list --installed | grep ssh
libssh-4/xenial,now 0.6.3-4.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libssh-gcrypt-4/xenial,now 0.6.3-4.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libssh2-1/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.5.0-2ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openssh-client/xenial-security,now 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.2]
openssh-server/xenial-security,now 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.2]
openssh-sftp-server/xenial-security,now 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.2]
ssh-askpass/xenial,now 1:1.2.4.1-9 amd64 [installed]
ssh-import-id/xenial,xenial,now 5.5-0ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
sshpass/xenial,now 1.05-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Doing this on RHEL v7 has no issues.